# Check if any user is currently logged in

Tags: 2010, development

I have a userID/userName, and I want to know if that user is currently loggedon to the SharePoint site.

The SPUser object does not seem to have any of these properties. I looked at Membership.GetUser("username").IsOnline, but that threw an "Access Denied" error.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Many Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I even tried to run with ElevatedPrivelges. The error is that current user does not has access to /APP_DATA folder.

Answer (score 2):

The disassembly for the IsOnline property looks like this:

return this.LastActivityDate.ToUniversalTime() > DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, SystemWebProxy.Membership.UserIsOnlineTimeWindow, 0));

Is it possible you could use the same methodology?

Not like this is an actual real time tracker or anything ...

The other option would be to provision a delegate control and use JavaScript object model to push user actions into a list.  You could probably just overload the SearchBoxEX control to add tracking.  Seems like a waste to me though.